# Will extreme cold damage hard drives?

Tags: weather, computers

At one point in Snowpiercer (the Netflix series)

> a character sacrifices her life

to keep some hard drives warm (or room temperature) in a research outpost in the context of a snowy post-apocalyptic world where the average outside temperature is -100°C.

Was this necessary? Would the hard drives have been readable if they were simply left in the freezing temperatures (indoor and in a closed hardshell case)?

Comment: What kind of hard drive?

Comment: After googling "can hard drives be damaged by cold temperatures", I found [something that might interest you](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/safe-temperature-store-hard-drive-66205.html). Welcome to the world building se, be sure to make the [tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help). A piece of advice: sometimes doing some research about what you want to ask can really pay out. You might even get the answers you were seeking in the first couple links you're shown if you're lucky.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about how this works in Snowpiercer? Or for your own fictional world? Context please!

Comment: Hello George. Did you ask this on the right Stack? Here at [worldbuilding.se] we help people develop the rules and systems of fictional worlds of their own creation. We specifically do not accept questions about 3rd-party or commercial worlds. Those questions are better asked at [scifi.se] or [movies.se]. Keep in mind that when it comes to a story: character actions are chosen to drive the plot and science has little-to-nothing to do with it. In other words, when you ask "was this necessary?" the answer is "yes... the plot required it."

Comment: If you look at the datasheets for hard drives (e.g. https://www.seagate.com/www-content/datasheets/pdfs/barracuda-pro-14-tb-DS1901-10-2006US-en_US.pdf), you'll often see operating (safe to run at) and non-operating temperature (storage) ranges.  In the example above, the manufacturer indicates -40°C to 70°C as the safe temp. range to store a HDD at.  So there probably are some problems that arise for a HDD stored at -100°C for any significant period of time.

Comment: (continued)  As to the specific nature of the problems that arise below the non-operating temperature, that would probably be a question better directed at the Electrical Engineering SE.  Based on my own limited knowledge, I would speculate that possibly the freezing of components (electrolytic capacitors, lubricants) would damage or denature them or possibly thermal expansion (most materials shrink slightly as the temp. drops but at different rates depending on the material) would flex or break connections and seals.

Comment: I haven't watched the movie in question, but -100 C is well outside the range for any standard electronics, simply because thermal contraction of the metal contacts from the normal operation of 30-40 C down to -100 C will destroy most components. From the movie title, the major threat would be the "snow". Moisture/condensate/any form of water getting on the plates would ruin them well before temperature became an issue

Comment: You would absolutely need to seal the harddrives from outside air. There might be problems with thermal contraction, but this is not likely for a device made to already survive more than 110C temperature range. the most likely is simple circuit board damage of the controller, and that would lead to easily repairable damage not data loss. The actual magnetic platters should be fine until they get superconductive, which will be under 2K.